# Unable to install CommVault on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, wine, 16.10, winetricks

I am trying to install **CommVault** on **Ubuntu 14.04(Virtual machine)** by executing the command `./cvpkgadd`, I am getting this error message `***wrong version of ksh:` then I tried to install by using `SetupAll.exe` through **wine**, it is getting crash, the error details are:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x000007c5 in 32-bit code (0x7e2974af).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:7e2974af ESP:01350100 EBP:01350138 EFLAGS:00010216(  R- --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:000006f9 EBX:7e2cc000 ECX:000006f9 EDX:78ab0fc1
 ESI:78ab0fc1 EDI:00000001
Stack dump:
0x01350100:  00177298 78ab0fc1 7e20a75d 7e297c41
0x01350110:  0006006a 0018086c 00000001 7e2cc000
0x01350120:  00175580 00180828 01350188 7e2cc000
0x01350130:  78ab0fc1 01350708 01350188 7e29a260
0x01350140:  00000000 00000000 00000000 8df35300
0x01350150:  00001000 00000001 001808a0 7e2cc000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7e2974af in comctl32 (+0x974af) (0x01350138)
  1 0x7e29a260 in comctl32 (+0x9a25f) (0x01350188)
  2 0x7e29eff9 in comctl32 (+0x9eff8) (0x01350318)
  3 0x7ec344ea WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x01350358)
  4 0x7ec34c26 in user32 (+0xa4c25) (0x013503a8)
  5 0x7ec375fb CallWindowProcW+0x5a() in user32 (0x013503ec)
  6 0x78833aef in mfc100u (+0x243aee) (0x0135040c)
  7 0x78834b63 in mfc100u (+0x244b62) (0x01350428)
  8 0x78832f6b in mfc100u (+0x242f6a) (0x013504a0)
  9 0x788331f7 in mfc100u (+0x2431f6) (0x013504c4)
  10 0x78729faf in mfc100u (+0x139fae) (0x01350508)
  11 0x7ec344ea WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x01350538)
  12 0x7ec34c26 in user32 (+0xa4c25) (0x01350588)
  13 0x7ec37383 in user32 (+0xa7382) (0x013505d8)
  14 0x7ebf619d in user32 (+0x6619c) (0x01350638)
  15 0x7ebfda46 in user32 (+0x6da45) (0x013506a8)
  16 0x7ebfdcd9 SendMessageW+0x58() in user32 (0x013506f0)
  17 0x7883ad8e in mfc100u (+0x24ad8d) (0x01350730)
  18 0x004c0e3c in setup (+0xc0e3b) (0x0135074c)
  19 0x004c12e6 in setup (+0xc12e5) (0x013507b4)
  20 0x004d3be1 in setup (+0xd3be0) (0x01353210)
  21 0x004d6c95 in setup (+0xd6c94) (0x01358fb4)
  22 0x0040e9dc in setup (+0xe9db) (0x01363000)
  23 0x004bd3a6 in setup (+0xbd3a5) (0x0137e6e4)
  24 0x004bf105 in setup (+0xbf104) (0x0138ff40)
  25 0x004c30a9 in setup (+0xc30a8) (0x013bf9d8)
  26 0x004116c7 in setup (+0x116c6) (0x013bfaa8)
  27 0x78834b4c in mfc100u (+0x244b4b) (0x013bfac8)
  28 0x78832f6b in mfc100u (+0x242f6a) (0x013bfb40)
  29 0x788331f7 in mfc100u (+0x2431f6) (0x013bfb64)
  30 0x78729faf in mfc100u (+0x139fae) (0x013bfba8)
  31 0x7ec344ea WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x013bfbd8)
  32 0x7ec34c26 in user32 (+0xa4c25) (0x013bfc28)
  33 0x7ec37383 in user32 (+0xa7382) (0x013bfc78)
  34 0x7ebf8425 DispatchMessageW+0xb4() in user32 (0x013bfd78)
  35 0x78821801 in mfc100u (+0x231800) (0x013bfdb8)
  36 0x7884778d in mfc100u (+0x25778c) (0x013bfdcc)
  37 0x004f0294 in setup (+0xf0293) (0x013bfe60)
  38 0x7b85e5cc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x013bfe78)
  39 0x7b85f653 in kernel32 (+0x4f652) (0x013bfeb8)
  40 0x7bc799b0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x013bfed8)
  41 0x7bc7c93d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x013bffa8)
  42 0x7bc7998e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x013bffc8)
  43 0x7bc4e8fe call_dll_entry_point+0x7ed() in ntdll (0x013bffe8)
  44 0xb75fc50d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  45 0xb75fc5cb wine_switch_to_stack+0x2a() in libwine.so.1 (0xbfbc7df8)
  46 0x7bc541e2 LdrInitializeThunk+0x3a1() in ntdll (0xbfbc7e58)
  47 0x7b865bdd __wine_kernel_init+0xa0c() in kernel32 (0xbfbc8f78)
  48 0x7bc547a3 __wine_process_init+0x192() in ntdll (0xbfbc9008)
  49 0xb75f9c70 wine_init+0x30f() in libwine.so.1 (0xbfbc9068)
  50 0x7bf00fdc main+0xfb() in <wine-loader> (0xbfbc94b8)
  51 0xb7427a83 __libc_start_main+0xf2() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x7e2974af: movl    0xcc(%eax),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (137 modules)
PE    250000-  30a000   Deferred        stlport.5.2
PE    310000-  33a000   Deferred        qinetwork
PE    400000-  9e9000   Export          setup
PE   13c0000- 14cb000   Deferred        installutils
PE  10000000-102a7000   Deferred        qiutils
PE  78050000-780b9000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  785f0000-78a2f000   Export          mfc100u
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 7ac00000-7ac5f000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac5f000   \               riched20
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7d1ea000-7d228000   Deferred        libxslt.so.1
ELF 7d228000-7d24e000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7d24e000-7d3a8000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
ELF 7d3a8000-7d466000   Deferred        msxml3<elf>
  \-PE  7d3b0000-7d466000   \               msxml3
ELF 7d466000-7d484000   Deferred        msxml<elf>
  \-PE  7d470000-7d484000   \               msxml
ELF 7d484000-7d4a9000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d490000-7d4a9000   \               imm32
ELF 7d533000-7d549000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d540000-7d549000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7d549000-7d552000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d552000-7d56a000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d56a000-7d56e000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d56e000-7d5b9000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d5b9000-7d5c5000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d5c5000-7d5f5000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d5f5000-7d6b3000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d6b3000-7d6c5000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d6c5000-7d6d3000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d6d3000-7d718000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d718000-7d785000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d785000-7d7bc000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d790000-7d7bc000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d7bc000-7d7c7000   Deferred        libltdl.so.7
ELF 7d7c7000-7d835000   Deferred        libodbc.so.1
ELF 7d849000-7d879000   Deferred        p11-kit-trust.so
ELF 7d879000-7d8b5000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d8b5000-7d8c9000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d8c9000-7d94f000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d94f000-7da15000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7da16000-7da29000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7da29000-7da2f000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da2f000-7da3a000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da3a000-7da4b000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da4b000-7da4f000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da4f000-7da5a000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7da5a000-7da65000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7da65000-7da6b000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7da6b000-7da6f000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7da6f000-7da76000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7da76000-7da7a000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7da7a000-7da9c000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7da9c000-7dbd0000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dbd0000-7dbe3000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dbe4000-7dbe9000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7dbe9000-7dbf0000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7dbf0000-7dbf5000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7dbf7000-7dc89000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dc00000-7dc89000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd06000-7dd2f000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd2f000-7dd6a000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dd6a000-7dd92000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dd92000-7de32000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de46000-7de83000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7de50000-7de83000   \               winhttp
ELF 7de83000-7dea3000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  7de90000-7dea3000   \               cabinet
ELF 7dea3000-7df45000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7deb0000-7df45000   \               urlmon
ELF 7df45000-7e041000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE  7df50000-7e041000   \               msi
ELF 7e041000-7e0b2000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e0b2000   \               setupapi
ELF 7e0b2000-7e0f2000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e0c0000-7e0f2000   \               winspool
ELF 7e0f2000-7e1dd000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e1dd000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e1dd000-7e1f5000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7e1e0000-7e1f5000   \               userenv
ELF 7e1f5000-7e2fc000   Dwarf           comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e200000-7e2fc000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e2fc000-7e52f000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e310000-7e52f000   \               shell32
ELF 7e52f000-7e549000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e549000-7e55d000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e550000-7e55d000   \               msimg32
ELF 7e55d000-7e5d9000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e5d9000   \               wininet
ELF 7e5d9000-7e601000   Deferred        odbc32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5e0000-7e601000   \               odbc32
ELF 7e601000-7e634000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7e610000-7e634000   \               secur32
ELF 7e634000-7e653000   Deferred        pdh<elf>
  \-PE  7e640000-7e653000   \               pdh
ELF 7e653000-7e789000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e670000-7e789000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e789000-7e80a000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e790000-7e80a000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e80a000-7e946000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e820000-7e946000   \               ole32
ELF 7e946000-7e9c0000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e950000-7e9c0000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e9c0000-7e9f6000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9d0000-7e9f6000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e9f6000-7ea1c000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ea00000-7ea1c000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7ea1c000-7ea49000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea20000-7ea49000   \               netapi32
ELF 7ea49000-7ea63000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7ea63000   \               version
ELF 7ea63000-7eb80000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea70000-7eb80000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb80000-7ecda000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb90000-7ecda000   \               user32
ELF 7ecda000-7ed02000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7ece0000-7ed02000   \               mpr
ELF 7ed02000-7ed74000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ed10000-7ed74000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ed74000-7ed81000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed81000-7ed8d000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed8d000-7eda6000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efa6000-7efec000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efec000-7f000000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               psapi
ELF b7404000-b740d000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF b740e000-b75bd000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF b75bd000-b75c2000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b75c3000-b75df000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b75f3000-b77a8000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b77aa000-b77cc000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b77cc000-b77cd000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
00000024 (D) Z:\mnt\hgfs\commvault\CVDownloads\Win32\Setup.exe
    00000025    0 <==
00000026 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.13.0-32-generic
```

Please suggest me any solution, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault, I forgot to check operating system bit type i.e., 32/64, I was installing 64bit commvault in to 32 bit operating system, haha, so, guys, before installing any application, double check the bit type of software application and bit type of operating system both. haha